# Mocking laravel environment in test

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit, environment-variables

I'm implementing some logic that requires code to behave differently in a production environment.

I want to write a test that asserts this actually happens, but I'm having difficulty mocking the environment.

I've [seen it suggested](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/is-it-possible-to-mock-the-applications-environment) to use `putenv('APP_ENV=production');` but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I make the test pass?

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Tests\TestCase;

class EnvTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testEnv()
    {
        // This assertion is fine
        $env = App::environment();
        $this->assertEquals('testing', $env);

        putenv('APP_ENV=production');

        // This assertion fails
        $env = App::environment();
        $this->assertEquals('production', $env);
    }
}
```

#### Result

> Time: 160 ms, Memory: 18.00MB
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) EnvTest::testEnv
>
> Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
>
> --- Expected
>
> +++ Actual
>
> @@ @@
>
> -'production'
>
> +'testing'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this question is a year old now, but for those who come looking like I did, this worked for me in 5.8

```
  public function test_config_env()
  {
    $this->app->detectEnvironment(function() {
      return 'production';
    });
    $this->assertEquals('production', app()->environment()); // pass
  }
```

Comment: Note that this approach will cause POST methods to fail with a 419 error if they need a CSRF token. I suppose this is because the app is booted with a 'testing' environment before the individual test is run and CSRF verification is disabled in testing.

Comment: @CorieSlate I'd imagine the kind of low-level thing being patched would throw an exception if application is in production. At least this is what I am using this for.

Answer (score 5):

```
use App;

//...

public function my_awesome_test() 
{
    // Number of times method environment() have to be invoked
    $number_of_calls_to_method = 2

    // Fake, that we have production environment
    App::shouldReceive('environment')
        ->times($number_of_calls_to_method)
        ->andReturn('production');

    // Make here whatever you want in Production environment
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but this actually doesnt work. App::environment() still returns something different.

Comment: In Laravel 7.x I'm getting Received Mockery_0_Illuminate_Foundation_Application::offsetGet(), but no expectations were specified

Answer (score 4):

[`App::environment()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L470) doesn't seem yo be reading from the config file!

```
public function test_config_env()
{
    $this->app['config']->set(['app.env' => 'production']);

    $this->assertEquals('production', $this->app['config']->get('app.env')); // pass
    $this->assertEquals('production', $this->app->environment()); // fail
}

public function test_env()
{
    $this->app['env'] = 'production';

    $this->assertEquals('production', config('app.env')); // fail
    $this->assertEquals('production', $this->app['config']->get('app.env')); // fail

    $this->assertEquals('production', $this->app['env']); // pass
    $this->assertEquals('production', $this->app->environment()); // pass
}
```

Tested on Laravel v5.3

Comment: `app()['env'] = 'production'` worked, the rest of the mocking methods yielded no results.

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the answer of @staskrak so the behaviour of the mock is exactly like calling `App::environment()` with or without arguments. It also **doesn't** throw similar errors like `Received Mockery_0_Illuminate_Foundation_Application::offsetGet(), but no expectations were specified`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

protected function mockEnvironment(string $environment)
{
    App::shouldReceive('environment')
        ->withAnyArgs()
        ->zeroOrMoreTimes()
        ->andReturnUsing(function ($args) use ($environment) {
            // Return the current environment if no args are passed
            if (!$args) {
                return $environment;
            }

            // Wrap the args in an array if it's not in array yet
            if (!is_array($args)) {
                $args = Arr::wrap($args);
            }

            // Check if the current environment is in the given args
            return in_array($environment, $args);
        });
    App::partialMock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `detectEnviroment` to temporarily change the environment variable:

```php
app()->environment('production') // False

app()->detectEnvironment(fn () => 'production');

app()->environment('production') // True
```